# Removing row from array based on duplicate value of a key

Tags: php

I have a array called `$data['job_list']` which is as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 2
            [job_title] => JQuery developer
            [job_desc] => Developer
            [job_slug] => 2-JQuery-developer
            [job_type] => 191
            [job_skill] => 2
            [job_salary] => 2
            [job_experience] => 1
            [company_name] => IGUTS
            [company_desc] => IGUTS is a fresh company
            [company_industry] => 24
            [company_address] => 35 Lawrence Street
            [company_state] => 35
            [company_city] => 650
            [user_id] => 1
            [concerned_fname] => Saswat
            [concerned_lname] => Routroy
            [contact] => 8961287928
            [date_of_post] => 26-04-2014
            [job_timestamp] => 1398517810
            [industry_id] => 191
            [industry_title] => Web Designer/Developer
            [p_cid] => 24
            [industry_slug] => 191-Web-Designer-Developer
            [industry_desc] => 
            [industry_image] => 
            [industry_priority] => 0
            [industry_timestamp] => 1396535046
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 1
            [job_title] => PHP developer
            [job_desc] => Developer
            [job_slug] => 1-PHP-developer
            [job_type] => 191
            [job_skill] => 1,2
            [job_salary] => 1
            [job_experience] => 1
            [company_name] => IGUTS
            [company_desc] => IGUTS Company
            [company_industry] => 24
            [company_address] => 35 Lawrence Street
            [company_state] => 35
            [company_city] => 650
            [user_id] => 1
            [concerned_fname] => Saswat
            [concerned_lname] => Routroy
            [contact] => 8961287928
            [date_of_post] => 18-04-2014
            [job_timestamp] => 1397842605
            [skill_id] => 2
            [skill_title] => JQuery
            [skill_slug] => 2-JQuery
            [industry] => 24
            [skill_timestamp] => 1397395987
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [job_id] => 2
            [job_title] => JQuery developer
            [job_desc] => Developer
            [job_slug] => 2-JQuery-developer
            [job_type] => 191
            [job_skill] => 2
            [job_salary] => 2
            [job_experience] => 1
            [company_name] => IGUTS
            [company_desc] => IGUTS is a fresh company
            [company_industry] => 24
            [company_address] => 35 Lawrence Street
            [company_state] => 35
            [company_city] => 650
            [user_id] => 1
            [concerned_fname] => Saswat
            [concerned_lname] => Routroy
            [contact] => 8961287928
            [date_of_post] => 26-04-2014
            [job_timestamp] => 1398517810
            [skill_id] => 2
            [skill_title] => JQuery
            [skill_slug] => 2-JQuery
            [industry] => 24
            [skill_timestamp] => 1397395987
        )

)
```

`[job_id] => 2` is present twice

What I want is that, the row with duplicate `job_id => 2` should be removed

How can I achieve that??

Comment: I havent tested, but I think array_unique would do the job for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jobIds = array();

foreach ($jobs as $key => $job) {
    if (in_array($jobIds, $job['job_id'])) {
        unset($jobs[$key]);
        continue;
    }
    $jobIds[] = $job['job_id'];
}

print_r($jobs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would cycle though each "job" and create an array of Job IDs. If I see the same ID twice then I would remove the duplicate and store it somewhere else if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As Matei Mihai stated, i made some minor changes in his script and bingo it solved..

Matei Mihai made a mistake regarding the data-type of arguments of the in_array() function

I fixed that.

here's my code

```
    $jobIds = array();

    for($i = 0;$i < count($data['job_list']); $i++ )
    {
        if (in_array($data['job_list'][$i]['job_id'], $jobIds))
            {
                unset($data['job_list'][$i]);
                continue;
            }
        $jobIds[] = $data['job_list'][$i]['job_id'];
    }
```